# Enforce two-factor authentication on all controllers / actions

Tags: identity, two-factor-authentication, asp.net-core-5.0, enforcement

I've built an authenticated .net core (5.0) web application using Identity (2.2) and set up two factor authentication using a smartphone authenticator app. This is all working fine. I'm now trying to configure the application to enforce the two-factor authentication so that in order to reach any controller / action (apart from those needed for the authentication process), a user MUST be two-factor authenticated, by which I mean they must have enabled 2FA, set up the smartphone authenticator app and then gone through the two-factor authentication process. I'm sure there must be an easy way to do this, but I'm unable to find any posts anywhere on how to do it. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should only need to add the `[Authorize]` attribute to the controllers you want to protect (or you could add a global authorize filter to implicitly apply the attribute everywhere.) 

Once the user is authenticated, it's too late to worry about whether they enabled 2FA and logged in with it -- that's a concern for your login process; if you require 2FA, don't let the user log in until that requirement has been met.

Comment: I think you're right, Mr T, I need to redesign my login process. Many thanks for your help.